# Why does my MySQL query only fails on one part of the script?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

My script outputs a MySQL error but only on one form.

I didn't try anything else really. I couldn't get my head around the problem since the connection works fine for signup and login forms.

```
<?php
        //Connection.php
    error_reporting(E_PARSE | E_ERROR );
    $server = "localhost";
    $username ="root";
    $password = "";
    $db="mydb";

    $conn = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password, $db);
    //check connection
    if(!$conn){
        die("connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }else{
        echo "<script> console.log('connected'); </script>";
    }

    if($_SESSION['LoggedInEmail']){
        session_start();
    }
?>

<?php
     include('header.php');
     include('connection.php');
     $name=$surname=$email=$hashedPassword='';

     if(session_status() != PHP_SESSION_NONE){
    session_start();
    $cookieEmail = $_COOKIE['email'];
    $query = "SELECT name, surname, password, email FROM users WHERE   email = '$cookieEmail'";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

                $name = $row['name'];
                $surname = $row['surname'];
                $email = $row['email'];
                $hashedPassword = $row['password'];
                $_SESSION['LoggedInName']=$name;
                $_SESSION['LoggedInSurname']=$surname;
                $_SESSION['LoggedInEmail']=$email;
            }


    }else{
                $logginError = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Wrong username/password combination</div>";
                echo "<script> console.log('Wrong username/password combination'); </script>";
    }

    $tempName=$tempSurname=$tempPassword=$tempNewPass=$updateError='';

    if(isset($_POST['update'])){

        $tempName = ValiForm($_POST['name']);
        $tempSurname = ValiForm($_POST['surname']);
        $tempPassword = ValiForm($_POST['password']);
        $tempNewPass = ValiForm($_POST['newPassword']);

        if($tempName!= '' && $tempSurname!= '' && $tempPassword != '' && $tempNewPass != ''){

            if(password_verify($tempPassword, $hashedPassword)){

                $tempNewPass = password_hash($tempNewPass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

                $query = "UPDATE name, surname, email, password  SET name='$tempName', surname='$tempSurname', email = '$email', password='$tempNewPass' WHERE email='$email'";
                $result =  mysql_query($conn,$query);

                if(mysqli_query($conn, $result)){
                    echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>New record in database</div>";
                    header("Location: index.php");
                    echo "<script> console.log(' combination'); </script>";
                }else{
                    echo "Error: ". $query . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
                    echo "<script> console.log('Wrong username/password combination'); </script>";
                }
            }else{
                echo "<script> console.log('Wrong username/password combination'); </script>";
            }
        }else{
            echo "<script> console.log('Wrong username/password combination'); </script>";
        }
    }

}else{
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: '. 'index.php');
    die();
}
?>
```

I get this error outputted from `echo "Error: ". $query . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);`:

> Error: UPDATE name, surname, email, password SET name='Henrique123',
>   surname='Araujo123', email = 'forthelolz@outlook.pt',
>   password='$2y$10$SvAjR91lC0FPxkrzRf7LuOK3I66WftiAK1iCW7c0yWFjETlCfoCc6'
>   WHERE email='forthelolz@outlook.pt'

Comment: You want to read about [SQL Injection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax for the [UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) is wrong.

```
$query = "UPDATE name, surname, email, password  SET name='$tempName', surname='$tempSurname', email = '$email', password='$tempNewPass' WHERE email='$email'";
```

It should be like:

```
$query = "UPDATE table_name SET column1='value1', column2='value2' WHERE columnX='valueX'";
```

For the code you provided the query would look like this:

```
$query = "UPDATE users SET name='$tempName', surname='$tempSurname', password='$tempNewPass' WHERE email='$email'";
```

You have another flaw in your code when testing if the update-query was successful.

```
$result =  mysql_query($conn,$query);

if(mysqli_query($conn, $result)){
```

Should be something like:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
if ($result) {
```

***Notice:*** As noted in the comments... your code is vulnerable. You should really read about SQL-injections and how to prevent them!

Comment: Unfortonatly this did not fix the error :/ it's my first time dealing with MySQL. I have a function that strips and removes html special characters, fortunatly I'm aware of mysql injections, but thanks for the heads up anways.

Comment: I updated the answer with a query-example for your code. Please test your code with this query and report if its working or what further errors you are getting.

Comment: Thanks again for getting back to me. Unfortunately the only error i get is the one i showed you previously in the post. My query was like the one you posted too. I believe that doing htmlspecialchars(trim($formData)) ; prevents mysql injections right? At least that was what i was told. Either way I'm getting the same error but with a diferent formed query. Error: UPDATE users SET name='Henrique123', surname='Araujo123', email='forthelolz@outlook.pt', password = '$2y$10$8CP4l7xJePTpi/DPVAgMYu9.5HUUvKqaCKqsJ8ddomNYVlZNb5NO.' WHERE email='forthelolz@outlook.pt'

Comment: I checked your code again and found another flaw in it that is part of your problem. I updated my answer with information about it at the bottom of my post. Hope this solves your problem. On the topic of sql-injections: `htmlspecialchars` is not the optimal solution to prevent injections, since it only counters a small variety of attack-vectors. You should start using the [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) with mysqli. There are plenty of information about this on the internet and even StackOverflow.

Comment: mysqli($conn, $query) is the fafest way to check if the query passed im told. Either way I tried it your way and I still had the same exact issue. I even tried copying the query for registration (which works fine) into this part of the code. Thanks on the mysql injection page, ill be sure to add it :)

Comment: Okay i managed to fix it. The problem was that mysqli_query() has to have a connection and a query respective as arguments and not a connection and a result query. Thanks for the info on the mysql injection problem with my code tho, and for all the time! Is there anyways I can make it up to you? I'm not sure it stackoverflow has a reputation system or smth

Comment: Glad you got your problem solved. You can accept the answer if it was helpful for you. *StackOverflow has indeed a [reputation system](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). Everytime you vote something (questions, answers or comments) up (that arrows pointing up in front of a post), that person gets reputation-points.*